# How to keep numbers' precision in C

Tags: c, precision

I am trying to store as user input a large number in C in the variable "num" using this piece of code.

```
    scanf("%e",&num); //input: 340282346638528859811704183484516925440
    printf("%1.20e\n", num); // output: 3.40282346638528860000e+038
```

However it loses precision after "886000000", it rounds up to 0.

I thought that in C, it stores the number in double format. How do I keep this precision for larger numbers?

Comment: Double precision is up to 17 significant digits which are all used in 'output'. You can stretch it a  bit (16 bits actually) using `long double`, but to support larger numbers, you'll need special libraries. The built in scalar types don't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most implementations, `double` has 53 bits of precision. That's about 17 decimal digits, which is what you seem to have.

You can use `long double` if available; on Intel platforms, that will give you another 11 bits of precision.

Beyond that, you'll need to find a multiprecision library.